# Shell grouping file repetitive pattern

Tags: shell, sorting, awk, scripting

Let say I have one file

```
a,anything,keyboard
b,anything,mouse
c,anything,door
a,anything,monitor
d,anything,keyboard
```

As result I want

```
a,anything,keyboard - monitor
b,anything,mouse
c,anything,door
d,anything,keyboard
```

Pattern "a" repeats and I want to merge "keyboard" and "monitor" as in the result.

My question is how to merge pattern that repeats in the beginning of each line (in this example, "a") into one line adding whats is different (in this example, adding the word "monitor"

cat file.csv | cut -d',' -f1 | sort -u
result:

```
a
b
c
d
```

I want the result:

```
a,anything,keyboard - monitor
b,anything,mouse
c,anything,door
d,anything,keyboard
```

Comment: What part of _sorting_ you need to achieve here?

Comment: I have incremented my question ;)

Comment: There are probably many duplicates about how to collect multiple values for a combination of keys, though I could not quickly find one which exactly duplicates this one.  This is not an uncommon problem; I encourage you to search for previous similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call it *grouping* not *sorting*.

***gawk*** (GNU awk) solution:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{ PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_str_asc" }{ a[$1]=($1 in a)? a[$1]" - "$3 : $0 }
         END{ asort(a); for(i in a) print a[i] }' file
```

The output:

```
a,anything,keyboard - monitor
b,anything,mouse
c,anything,door
d,anything,keyboard
```